# PySide, Connecting PushButton error

Tags: qt, pyside

I am trying to make a simple test application in PySide and I am really not understanding what I am missing.  Here's the code so far:

```
    import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class IPTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BartonTest, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        lblAddress = QtGui.QLabel("IP Address", self)
        lineAddress = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        lblPort = QtGui.QLabel("Port Number", self)
        linePort = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        btnSend = QtGui.QPushButton("Send", self)
        btnReceive = QtGui.QPushButton("Receive", self)

        lblAddress.move(30, 20)
        lblPort.move(30, 60)
        lineAddress.move(130, 20)
        linePort.move(130, 60)
        btnSend.move(30, 100)
        btnReceive.move(130, 100)




        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 275, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Send/Receive TCP Test Program')
        self.show()

    def sendData(self):
        fileName, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOPenFileName(self, 'Open CNC Program')
        self.data = open(fileName, 'r')



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    bt = IPTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now what I want to do is just connect an event to the Pushbutton.  Qt's documentation tells me all I need to do is this:

```
btnSend.clicked.connect(self.sendData)
```

PyCharm says it cannot find the reference in clicked and the exception I get is

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

I am pretty (easily) stumped.

Comment: that looks right.  Can you post exactly what you were doing that wasn't working?

Comment: I guess you forgot `.connect` part and did `btnSend.clicked(self.sendData)`. This would give you the error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works correctly for me:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class IPTest(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IPTest, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        lblAddress = QtGui.QLabel("IP Address", self)
        lineAddress = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        lblPort = QtGui.QLabel("Port Number", self)
        linePort = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        btnSend = QtGui.QPushButton("Send", self)
        btnReceive = QtGui.QPushButton("Receive", self)

        lblAddress.move(30, 20)
        lblPort.move(30, 60)
        lineAddress.move(130, 20)
        linePort.move(130, 60)
        btnSend.move(30, 100)
        btnReceive.move(130, 100)

        btnSend.clicked.connect(self.sendData)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 275, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Send/Receive TCP Test Program')
        self.show()

    def sendData(self):

        fileName, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open CNC Program')
        if len(fileName) > 0:
            self.data = open(fileName, 'r')
```

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.  Must be something stupid I forgot.  I just copied and pasted yours and it worked as expected.  Thanks for your time

Comment: @Dan also note the change in `SendData` so it does not blow up if you hit 'cancel' in the dialog;)  You also had a typo in the `Super` call that refers to `BartonTest`